# `SELECT INTO` multiple variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, select-into

I'm having issue assigning multiple variables at once. Running the code below

```sql
SELECT v1, v2 INTO x, y FROM (VALUES (1, 2)) AS t (v1, v2);
```

throws an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
> LINE 1: select v1, v2 into x, y from (values (1,2)) as t (v1, v2);

Link to dbfiddle:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=98285b190de7871354ccb444d17eb25f

Would anyone be able to help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL variables in Postgres are not supported. You can use this kind of assignment in [PL/pgSQL language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql.html), in a function or an [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-do.html), e.g.:

```
do $$
declare 
    x int; 
    y int;
begin
    select v1, v2 into x, y 
    from (values (1,2)) as t (v1, v2);
end $$;
```

[db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=27642afd6d3d681619e4a8cddf904eb4)

Answer (score 0):

Use the aliases separately right next to each output as follows:

`select v1 as x, v2 as y from (values (1,2)) as t(v1,v2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple values to multiple variables with an [SELECT INTO statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) at once as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
  x INT;
  y INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO x, y FROM (VALUES (1, 2));
  RAISE INFO 'x=% y=%', x, y; -- x=1 y=2
END $$;
```

Or, you can use an `AS` clause. *Omitting `t.` and `AS` still work:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
  x INT; 
  y INT;
BEGIN                                           -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
  SELECT t.v1, t.v2 INTO x, y FROM (VALUES (1, 2)) AS t (v1, v2);
  RAISE INFO 'x=% y=%', x, y; -- x=1 y=2
END $$;
```

Or, you can set an `INTO` clause to the end:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
  x INT;
  y INT;
BEGIN                        -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 2)) INTO x, y;
  RAISE INFO 'x=% y=%', x, y; -- x=1 y=2
END $$;
```

Or, you can set an `INTO` clause to the end. *Omitting `t.` and `AS` still work:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
  x INT; 
  y INT;
BEGIN                                               -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
  SELECT t.v1, t.v2 FROM (VALUES (1, 2)) AS t (v1, v2) INTO x, y;
  RAISE INFO 'x=% y=%', x, y; -- x=1 y=2
END $$;
```